# Getting element that is created with vue2, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have couple of inputs which I created with `v-for` and I have structured them like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" :id="'info[' + client + '][' + index + '][name]'"
```

So, id of an element is for example `info[1][1][name]`. I can confirm it in inspector.

Now, I am trying to change it's value. The easiest way seemed jQuery to me, because I need to get field information from another component and write on this input (and I knew the `client` & `index` so I could `$() easily`).

As id of our element is `info[1][1][name]`, I tried using `$('#info[1][1][name])` in the console but I couldn't get it. Also tried `$('body').find('#info[1][1][name])`, but no luck either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `[` and `]` are [used by CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to match attributes, you need to [escape those](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/) if they are legit parts of your `id`.

```
$('#info\\[1\\]\\[1\\]\\[name\\]')
```